# django template: floatformat filter not working when used within an if-condition

Tags: django, django-templates

In my template, I have:

```
 {% if subject.market_value_increase_pct > subject.neighborhood_increase_pct %}
```

Values provided are:
`market_value_increase_pct` = 8.6 & `neighborhood_increase_pct` = 10.5

I expect the if-condition should evaluate to `false` with these values. However, it was evaluating to `true` and the code block within the if-condition was being executed. My thought was may be the variables are being considered as strings, in which case it would evaluate to `true`. So, I tried to force convert the values to float using [floatformat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat) and then compare:

```
  {% if subject.market_value_increase_pct|floatformat > subject.neighborhood_increase_pct|floatfomat %}
```

But, that isn't working. It still evaluates to `true`. The `floatformat` filter works outside of the if-condition though:

```
<td>{{ subject.market_value_increase_pct|floatformat }}%</td>
```

As per [Django template docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#filters), using filters in if-condition is permitted.

Would appreciate if anyone can point out what I am missing. Below is the complete code block:

```
 {% if subject.market_value_increase_pct|floatformat > subject.neighborhood_increase_pct|floatfomat %}
        <tr>
             <th>Subject's market value last year:</th>
             <td>{{ subject.market_value_last_year | currency | remove_decimal_point}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Percent increase:</th>
            <td>{{ subject.market_value_increase_pct|floatformat}}%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Average percentage increase for state class {{subject.state_class}} in neighborhood {{ subject.neighborhood_code }}:</th>
            <td>{{ subject.neighborhood_increase_pct|floatformat}}%</td>
        </tr>

{% endif %}
```

I tried using `add:"0"` and `int` filters also. None of them work. Basically, filters aren't working within if-condition in Django template for me.